# Building a CLI Batch for Windows upon usage of FFmpeg Video Conversor

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

Here what ive done for WINDOWS users:

but getting an error if any can help!

Check code:

```
@echo off
set /P file="Say the FILE EXTENTION.: "

(for %i in (*.%file%) do (
    @echo ffmpeg.exe -i %i -vf scale=480:320 %i-.mp4 > %file%-em-lista.bat
    
    ))

echo Now wait Batch File Created Started Convert, make sure having ffmpeg installed at system32
start %file%-em-lista.bat
```

Also I noticed i got stucked, it does works out in CMD typed dirrecly:

Give a check, this command will enumerate all txt files at your folder:

```
FOR %f in (dir /b *.txt) do (echo %f)
```

Guess its a not know code declaration or concatenation, im already at the 3th day trying it out of sevaral ways.

```
@echo off

set /P fext="SAY VIDEO FORMAT.: "
set /P xpath="SAY FOLDER OR VIDEO LOCATION FOR BATCH CREATION.: "
set current_dir=%xpath%

echo "Your Current Directory IS: %current_dir%"

FOR /f %i in (dir /b *.%fext%) do (
        
        @echo ffmpeg.exe -i %i -vf scale=480:320 -v error -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_device 0 %i.mp4 > %xext%-em-lista.bat
        
        )
echo "Starting Conversions"
start %fext%-em-lista.bat 
echo Wait Conversions Finish
end
```

Since yesterday: UPDATED code working Stable inside Videos Folder 24/07/20

```
@echo off

echo ###Set the VideoExample.Ext you are going to converto to MP4####

set /P file="Say the FILE EXTENTION.: "


REM going to make a if later for not Nvidia GC cuz of CUDA Aceleration not found in any Freeware Software REM

(for %%i in (*.%file%) do @echo ffmpeg.exe -v error -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_device 0  -i %%i -acodec copy -f mp4 -ac 2 -vf scale=480:320 %%i.mp4) > %file%-to-mp4-em-lista2.bat

echo Wait Process Finish *-*
start %file%-to-mp4-em-lista2.bat
```

As far now, need improvements for

Options:
[1] make a default folder for IN and OUT converted Videos
[2] make a inseted DIR-PATH workable IN and OUTPUT Videos

Videos to Audio and sort of FFMPEG options as we like.

Comment: You seriously created this question three hours after your last  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063466/usage-of-for-in-batch-file-instead-of-cmd-not-gives-same-result) and didn't bother to read or understand any of the comments in that question.

Comment: I didnt noticed that, but im going to uptade progress since then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference a variable in a `FOR` loop inside a batch script, you must use double %:

```
FOR /f %%i in (dir /b *.%fext%) do
```

Some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for):

> Use a single percent sign (%) to carry out the for command at the
> command prompt. Use double percent signs (%%) to carry out the for
> command within a batch file. Variables are case sensitive, and they
> must be represented with an alphabetical value such as %a, %b, or %c.

Comment: Done and updated the code uphere with the workeable version finished, im tired now 3-4 days working but i didnt know much of batch in windows lol